# Gtk.FileChooserButton does not react to Gtk.FileChooserAction.SELECT_FOLDER

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.4, gtk3, filechooser

I am using the `gi.repository.Gtk` module to generate some GUIs.

To let the user select a ***folder*** I use the `gi.repository.Gtk.FileChooserButton`.
According to the Gtk3 documentation I should be able to select or create folders using the action `Gtk.FileChooserAction.SELECT_FOLDER`or `Gtk.FileChooserAction.CREATE_FOLDER`.

So the relevant code is this:

```
filechooser = Gtk.FileChooserButton(Gtk.FileChooserAction.CREATE_FOLDER)
filechooser.connect("file-set",update_select_folder)

def update_select_folder(*args):
    print(*args)
```

But I am still unable to select/create folders.( I am able to select *files*.)

- [Python3 Gtk3 Documentation](http://learngtk.org/tutorials/python_gtk3_tutorial/html/filechooserbutton.html)
- complete Code on [github](https://github.com/daknuett/BeeKeeper/blob/master/objs_graphics.py)

So my Question is: *How can I select/create folders using a FileChooserButton?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooser.html

```py
filechooser = Gtk.FileChooserButton()
filechooser.set_action(Gtk.FileChooserAction.SELECT_FOLDER)
filechooser.set_create_folders(True)
```

Comment: This does not work. I am still unable to select/create folders.

Comment: What if you call filechooser.set_action(Gtk.FileChooserAction.SELECT_FOLDER)

Comment: yap, that was it! thank you. but why do I need this anyway? shouldn't this be done by `FileChooserButon.__init__`? please edit your answer.

Comment: I'm curious if ```filechooser = Gtk.FileChooserButton(action=Gtk.FileChooserAction.SELECT_FOLDER)``` would work. The documentation is not clear to me on how to properly use the constructor.

Comment: nope `filechooser = Gtk.FileChooserButton(action=Gtk.FileChooserAction.SELECT_FOLDER)` does not work either. The documentation is weird.

Comment: "The documentation is weird."
I agree.